Grok pattern does not work for empty line
I am new to the glue. I am trying to read fix fixed-width file using Glue Grok. It works fine if the file does not have an empty line but it fails when the file has an empty line.
for example, case1 is working but case 2 does not
case 1: abcdef1234 ghijkl4567
case 2: abcdef1234 ghijkl4567
glue pattern I am using as follows
(?.{3})(?.{3})(?<c3:int>.{4})(/^\s*|\s*$|\s*(\r?\n)\s*/g)


@parman .. Thanks for edit. Can you please suggest some solution?
